# DstMultipartUploadNotPermitted during cross-account S3 replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, replication

I have two S3 buckets in two different regions on two different accounts. I want to use a S3 replication rule to replicate all files (including existing ones) from **bucket-a** to **bucket-b**.

bucket-a is an existing bucket with objects in it already, bucket-b is a new, empty bucket.

I created a replication rule and ran the batch operation job to replicate existing objects. After the job finished, **63% of objects failed to replicate, with the errors `DstPutObjectNotPermitted` or `DstMultipartUploadNotPermitted`** and no further information. Nothing comes up on Google for these errors. (these are coming from the csv file that gets generated after job completion). The remaining objects got replicated as expected.

---

Here's my configuration:

bucket-a has versioning enabled and it is encrypted with a default aws-managed KMS key. ACL's are enabled, and this is the bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "NoBucketDelete",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "NoBucketDeleteStatement",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:DeleteBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

bucket-b also has versioning and ACL's enabled, and is encrypted with a customer-managed key.

The bucket policy is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1644945280205",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1644945277847",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::12345:role/bucket-replication-role"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ReplicateObject",
                "s3:ReplicateTags",
                "s3:ObjectOwnerOverrideToBucketOwner",
                "s3:ReplicateDelete"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

...and the KMS key policy is

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "key-consolepolicy-3",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow access through S3 for all principals in the account that are authorized to use S3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "kms:CallerAccount": "12345",
                    "kms:ViaService": "s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::12345:root"
            },
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow access for Key Administrators",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::12345:user/root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::12345:user/user"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Create*",
                "kms:Describe*",
                "kms:Enable*",
                "kms:List*",
                "kms:Put*",
                "kms:Update*",
                "kms:Revoke*",
                "kms:Disable*",
                "kms:Get*",
                "kms:Delete*",
                "kms:TagResource",
                "kms:UntagResource",
                "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
                "kms:CancelKeyDeletion"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::12345:user/user"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow attachment of persistent resources",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::12345:user/user"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:CreateGrant",
                "kms:ListGrants",
                "kms:RevokeGrant"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a role in account-a, *bucket-replication-role*, with a trust relationship allowing S3 assume role and an attached policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

and an attached policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ReplicateDelete"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:12345:key/[account-a-kms-key-id]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:GenerateDataKey",
                "kms:Encrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:12345:key/[account-b-kms-key-id]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ObjectOwnerOverrideToBucketOwner"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ReplicateObject",
                "s3:ReplicateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my replication rule, on bucket-a
[image: replication rule]

The above role is attached as well, during creation.

and the batch operation is the default one that gets prompted on the replication rule creation.

The files are just small png's, jsons, html files, etc- nothing weird in there. You can see the replication status FAILED in the object information

[image: replication failed]

Most of my policy rules came from this AWS support page: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-replication/

---

*Update*

I added the following policy to account-b KMS key:

```
{
    "Sid": "AllowS3ReplicationSourceRoleToUseTheKey",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::12345:role/bucket-replication-role"
    },
    "Action": ["kms:GenerateDataKey", "kms:Encrypt"],
    "Resource": "*"
}
```

and the `DstPutObjectNotPermitted` errors have gone away, now its just the `DstMultipartUploadNotPermitted` errors I'm seeing.

---

*Update 2*

I tried to recreate the issue with two new buckets, and can not reproduce the issue, so I assume it's something to do with how some of the older files in bucket-a are stored.

Comment: Have you tried (temporarily) removing the `Deny` rule in the bucket-b Bucket Policy to see if it helps? If that doesn't help, then try (temporarily) removing the `Deny` rules in the bucket-a policy.

Comment: @John Rotenstein Good suggestion. I tried and am unfortunately still having the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This required some help from AWS Support, this was the relevant points of their response:

> "DstMultipartUploadNotPermitted" status code indicates that the source objects are multipart uploads and the permissions required for their replication haven't been granted in the resource policies. Note that if a source object is uploaded using multipart upload to the source bucket, then the IAM replication role will also upload the replica object to destination bucket using multipart upload.

> I would like to inform you that some extra permissions are to be granted for allowing multipart uploads in an S3 bucket. The list of permissions required for the IAM replication role to perform multipart uploads when KMS encryption is involved are listed below.
>
> - s3:PutObject on resource "arn:aws:s3:::DESTINATION-BUCKET/*"
> - kms:Decrypt and kms:GenerateDataKey on resource "arn:aws:kms:REGION:DESTINATION-ACCOUNT-ID:key/KEY-ID"

...as well as

> ensure that the destination bucket policy is granting the "s3:PutObject" permission on resource "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b/*" to the IAM replication role "arn:aws:iam::12345:role/bucket-replication-role".

...and finally

> I would also request you to please grant "kms:Decrypt", and "kms:GenerateDataKey" permissions on the destination KMS key to the IAM replication role "arn:aws:iam::12345:role/bucket-replication-role" in the destination KMS key policy.

After adding all these additional permissions, everything worked as expected.